# PHP MVC loads default controller but won't URL rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using PIP mvc. I set the default controller to "main", and so my base URL loads fine. When I try to access a URL using the "example.com/main/index" style, I get a 404 error.

I'm using OS X 10.8.2 and a virtual host in my home dir.

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

I know the htaccess file is being read by apache because I removed "Options -Indexes" and was able to browse the filesystem.

It matches the one that comes in the download of PIP.

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is, that mod_rewrite is not enabled.

Comment: I did "$ apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES |grep rewrite" and it returned  "rewrite_module (shared)"

Comment: Try removing the `<ifmodule ...>` and `</ifmodule>`

Comment: Unfortunately no change ;-(

Comment: Is there a file called `main.xxx`. If so try adding `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: Tried it out - same issue.

Comment: I think I may have to install a new version of Ubuntu server and try again with that